# Angular2 - Assign value directly within *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a sortable list which I can drag and sort the item inside it. That is to say the `index` of the `li` from `ngFor` changes dynamically. I eliminate the sortable part and please just look into how I can assign `i+1` to `el.someProperty` every time the `i` changed.

I used `@viewChildren` to pass the input to components but do not know what the next. `[(ngModel)]` here is only for demonstration purpose.

```
<li *ngFor="let el of els; let i = index">
  <input [value]="i+1" #input [(ngModel)]=el.someProperty>
</li>
```